# Query function suddenly returning `None` instead of the item it should be retruning

Tags: python, sqlite

I did some minor refactoring to some working code. All I did was add 2 functions to clean up how input and it's assignment was handled. I did not change anything about the `query_pswd_by_name` function but now it doesn't return the password, it returns `None`. Everything else works perfectly. Any ideas what is going on? Here is the code:

````
import secrets 
import string
import sqlite3
import pyperclip
import optparse

#CREATE PASSWORD OF GIVEN LENGTH
def get_pass(length):
    return "".join(secrets.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits + string.punctuation) for x in range(length))


def get_pass_length():
    length = int(input("Enter the length of password: "))
    password= get_pass(length)
    print(password)
    pyperclip.copy(password)
    print('Password copied to clipboard')

def create_and_store_pwsd():
    password = get_pass_length()
    name = str(input("Enter name for password: "))

    #CREATE DATABASE CONNECTION
    conn = sqlite3.connect("managerDB.db")

    #CREATE CURSOR OBJECT
    c = conn.cursor()

    #CREATE TABLE IN DISK FILE BASED DATABASE
    c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS password_table (
                            name TEXT,
                            pswd TEXT
                            )""")
    #c.execute("DELETE FROM password_table")
    c.execute("INSERT INTO password_table (name, pswd) VALUES (?, ?)", (name, password))

    #COMMIT CHANGES
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()


def query_pswd_by_name(name):

    conn = sqlite3.connect('managerDB.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    query_password = "SELECT pswd FROM password_table WHERE name = ?"
    c.execute(query_password,(name,))
    result = c.fetchall()
    for row in result:
        pyperclip.copy(str(row[0]))
        print("Password copied to clipboard")
        print(str(row[0]))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

def input_name_and_query():
    name = input('Name of password you wish to query: ')
    query_pswd_by_name(name)

create_and_store_pwsd()

input_name_and_query()```
````

Comment: I solved it. I needed a `return password` statement in my get_pass_length() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mean, at face value, it returns `None` because you never return anything from the function. You are copying it to the clip board.

A bit more detail would be good. What functions were refactored? What is the output to the console of all your print statements?

As an aside, I'd recommend wrapping the module functionality (last two calls) in an `if __name__ == "__main__"` block

Comment: Thanks, shortly after i posted this i realized i didnt have a return statement. I'm not sure how to declare a post as solved without using the checkmark next to someone's solution, so i just posted a comment saying i solved it. but to answer your questions:
`get pass` and `query_pswd_by_name` were refactored and  `get_pass_length` and input_name_and_query were added. Print statements were returning what i asked them to('Password copied to clipboard' and the one's that were supposed to print the actual password were what were returning None.  as for the `if __name__` block, what will this do?

Comment: ive used the if __name__==__main__ when i had a main() function defined, but dont really get what it's for, or how it helps without a main function defined

Comment: The `if __name__ == "__main__"` is good coding practice and forces you to separate code you are executing from code you are just defining things in. Useful for when you end up importing the library for its definitions and don't want the executional stuff running. 

Since my answer was correct I'd appreciate it if you'd indicate as such by using the checkmark. Thanks!

Comment: Check marked! Thanks again, sorry about that, kinda new around here.